Error While Starting GridDB Node.js Application Container
I’m begineer to GridDB and trying to run the docker container. I’ve gone through the documentation and followed the initial steps—everything from running the GridDB server to getting the JDBC sample container up and running. But now, I’m getting blocked.
When I try to run the GridDB Node.js Application Container following the instructions here, I’m getting a strange error in Docker. The Java sample application  container runs just fine, but the Node.js application refuses to work.
Here’s the error I’m seeing:
2024-07-31 17:39:41 FATAL ERROR: Error: : New napi_get_last_error_info
2024-07-31 17:39:41 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [node]
2024-07-31 17:39:41 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
2024-07-31 17:39:41 3: 0xa1c19c [node]
2024-07-31 17:39:41 4: 0xad1abb napi_fatal_error [node]
2024-07-31 17:39:41 5: 0x7f313d071d4e [/app/node_modules/griddb-node-api/griddb.node]

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
Thank you.
I try to find a suitable docker container to fix that issue but there was none. The docker I am currently try to make work is of the offical Documentation of GridDb.
